# JSF submits no values to my class

Tags: jsf-2

somewhere in my code i made a stupid mistake, but i can't find it. Im using an jsf-page for adding new movies to a database.

```
<h:form id="MovieForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="fixed-column">
        Titel  <h:inputText id="title">#{moviePM.title}</h:inputText>
        Direktor <h:inputText id="director">#{moviePM.director}</h:inputText>
        Erscheinungsjahr <h:inputText id="year">#{moviePM.year}</h:inputText>
        Altersbeschränkung <h:selectOneMenu value="#{moviePM.rating}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{moviePM.ratings}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Film hinzufügen" action="#{moviePM.addMovie()}" />
</h:form>
```

Im using following Class for take the results of the jsf page

```
import business.MovieService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import model.Movie;
import model.Rating;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MoviePM implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private MovieService service;

    private String director;
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private Rating rating;

    public void addMovie() {
        Logger.getLogger(MoviePM.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "###" + director + " " + title + " " + year + " " + rating + "###");
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setDirector(director);
        movie.setTitle(title);enter code here
        movie.setYear(year);
        movie.setRating(rating);
        service.create(movie);

    }
```

I got also getters and setters but i left them out of this post.

The Logger provides following Result: INFO:   ###null null 0 FSKAB16###

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `value="..."` to connect your inputs to the bean properties. Just like you did it for the rating.

```
<h:form id="MovieForm">
    <h:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="fixed-column">
        Titel: <h:inputText id="title" value="#{moviePM.title}" />
        Direktor: <h:inputText id="director" value="#{moviePM.director}" />
        Erscheinungsjahr: <h:inputText id="year" value="#{moviePM.year}" />
        Altersbeschränkung: <h:selectOneMenu value="#{moviePM.rating}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{moviePM.ratings}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:commandButton value="Film hinzufügen" action="#{moviePM.addMovie()}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Oh, embarrassing. Thanks for the quick response and sorry for wasting your time :D